# How to change controls in edit or new form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In my share point site collection have one list, so how to convert the text box of one field into range control or some other control.?

I can see only the following code,

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff23{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Certifications" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff23',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Certifications')}"/>
<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff23description{$Pos}" FieldName="Certifications" ControlMode="New"/>
```

but it displays only text box,i don't know how the textbox displays in that area, and what i want to do, to get the some other controls like input type="range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to do it with javascript.

```
document.getElementById("id_of_field").type="range";
```

You may want to add jQuery to the page if you haven't already it makes it easier to lookup the field:

```
$("input[title='Certifications']").type = "range";
```